# API response in XML badly encoded, how to correct/convert the string?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm querying certain API with HttpClient that sends XML request and receives XML response.

```
var response = await this.httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")));
var responseXml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

However `responseXml` contains

```
<errorMessage>Je vyÅ¾adovÃ¡na autentizace.</errorMessage>
```

It's supposed to be **Je vyžadována autentizace**. Any idea what might be causing this behavior and how to get the correct string out of it?

Comment: Seems like Response text language is czech. `Je vyÅ¾adovÃ¡na autentizace.` Translation is `Authentication is required.` - Have you missed any authentication Token as part of api Request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spent hours on this and just as I wrote the question I came up with solution.

Had to switch from `ReadAsStringAsync()` to `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` and decode it as UTF8, the response was encoded in ISO-8859-1.

```
var responseXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
```

Comment: This will load the entire response content into memory, which might be inefficient for very large responses. You could also use the Stream to read the response. `using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); using var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8); // Or you can use Encoding.Unicode as per your need string responseStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();`